# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API: how to protect sensitive data from return with model?

Tags: asp.net-core, serialization, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a `Posts` model class that has a relation with `Users` model.
When I call API to get `Posts` with the owner of it (user), it returns with all user info including password.

How to prevent model from returning sensitive information like passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create new classes that you return from your actions. Only include the fields/information you want to return.
These classes are also known as Data Transfer Objects (DTO).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[JsonIgnore]` to avoid serializing the property value:

```
public class Users 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
    public string Password{ get; set; }
    //...
}
```